# how to Apply/lambda with Apply Function in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

I am a beginner in Pandas and I was trying the following:

I have two data sets:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3,4,5]})
df6 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3,4,5] ,"Name":["Tom","Dick","Harry","Mike","Sam"]})
```

I would like to replace the ids in df5 with the actual names from df6 using apply or lambda apply. I have tried the following:

```
def extract_name2 (x):
    name = df6[df6["ID"] == x]["Name"]
    return name
df5["id"].apply(extract_name2)
```

This is my output:

```
Out[120]: 
0     1      2     3    4
0  Tom   NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
1  NaN  Dick    NaN   NaN  NaN
2  NaN   NaN  Harry   NaN  NaN
3  NaN   NaN    NaN  Mike  NaN
4  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  Sam
```

I also tried:

```
df5["id"].apply(lambda x: df6[df6["ID"] == x]["Name"])
```

But same result

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please indicate your expected output.

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag for python questions. Use a version specific tag at your discretion

Comment: You don't want to use `.apply` here. `.apply` in general is a last resort. Use pandas indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `df6[df6["ID"] == x]` the output is a dataframe filtered based on the condition you give.

You need to specify that you need the first cell value from the `'Name'` column of the filtered dataframe.

This will give you your desired result:

```
df5['id'].apply(lambda x: df6[df6['ID'] == x]['Name'].iloc[0])
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also do this without using `apply`. Use `merge`:

```
pd.merge(df5, df6, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='ID')
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  ID  Name
1   1   Tom
2   2   Dick
3   3   Harry
4   4   Mike
5   5   Sam
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iloc:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3,4,5]})
df6 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3,4,5] ,"Name":["Tom","Dick","Harry","Mike","Sam"]})

def extract_name2 (x):
    name = df6[df6["ID"] == x]["Name"].iloc[0]
    return name
print(df5["id"].apply(extract_name2))
```

Output:

```
0      Tom
1     Dick
2    Harry
3     Mike
4      Sam
```